# trying to keep original array (cloning, react)

Tags: reactjs

I'm making a menu app where people can filter food and drinks. It's divided in categories, and categories contain items. One of the properties is 'alcohol' -> does the drink contain alcohol?

I have a state-object with 2 arrays: an 'original' array (containig all items) and a 'filter' array (where the filtering happens).

Every time a filter is changed, I want to copy the original array and start filtering all over again. But it seems that after filtering one time, the original array is changed, and it's weird because I clone the array.

My code:

```
const [arrays, setArrays] = useState({
  original: [{ catName: 'drinks', items: [{},{},...]}],
  filter: [] // same as original in the beginning
});

useEffect(() => {
  const copy = [...arrays.original];
  copy.forEach((cat, idx) => {
    if (!filter.alcohol) {
      copy[idx].items = cat.items.filter(e => e.properties.alcohol === false);
    }
  });
  setArrays(p => ({
    ...p,
    filter: copy
  });
}, [filter]);
```

I never 'touch' the original array, but after a filter changes, not only the 'filter'-array is changed (like expected), but also the original array.

**Edit: expected behaviour:**
when I filter on alcohol, I'm expecting that all drinks containing alcohol are removed from the filter-array. This works, but when I remove the filter, all the alcohol-drinks should be back in the filter-array. This doesn't work because they are also deleted from the original array.

Comment: do you know that objects are passed by reference in javascript? that's what you are doing. you create a new array but you fill it with references to the same objects as in the original. what you are looking for is a deep copy.

Comment: You don't copy arrays, you copy the object that contains arrays and then iterate over them. You need to clone each array inside `copy.forEach`

Comment: Thank you for your answers. How do I perform a deep copy?

Comment: No worries, I found it already. Lodash's deepClone does the trick! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you may just be returning a shallow copy of the original array. Have you tried Lodash's clonedeep?